# unable to validate image upload form using struts2 interceptor

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, interceptor

i am trying to put validation into my `image upload` form using struts2 interceptor if users submits invalid image extension there there should be    validation error message?

uploadThemeImage.jsp

```
<s:form action="updatethemeimageform"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="remoteform"  theme="simple" >
     <s:hidden value="%{#parameters.themeid}" name="themId"/>  
      <s:file name="thempic" label="Theme Screenshot" /> 
      <sj:a button="true" id="btnsid" buttonIcon="ui-icon-gear" dataType="json" indicator="indicator"  onSuccessTopics="reloadMyGrid,handleJsonResult"  
        formIds="remoteform" targets="result">Submit This Form</sj:a>  </s:form>
```

Comment: You're saying if it's an invalid image that validation works? Why do you want the action to run if it's an invalid image?

Comment: @DaveNewton  I am trying to show error message into my image upload form, if users selects invalid image extension.  Error like http://cdn.dzone.com/static/images/vaannila/struts2/FileUpload1Pic2.gif

Comment: So you're saying there's no validation message?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes Exactly.

Comment: Does your action implements `ValidationAware` interface?

Comment: @AleksandrM Please give me hint why my validation message is not printing in my jsp page.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: Hmm... try to use default stack with configured `fileUpload` interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the error if you don't put an `<s:fielderror />` tag in your JSP.

Add it before `<s:form>` and you will see your validation error...

P.S: the same applies to `<s:actionmessage />` and `<s:actionerror >` (that are not involved with the validation but added by you)

Comment: Thanks But still my image is not showing into my jsp  page.. i will try again for next few hour . If i don'nt get my result then i will get back to you

Comment: This was not related to show your image in JSP page, this was for showing your Validation Error in your JSP page...

Comment: Yeah that i know. If i add `actionMessage("Succuss")` or `actionErrorMessage("Error message goes here")` in class. then this will be shown in jsp. But here i am trying to implement interceptor file upload validation\